# Anyone about me how we make games in Android , also about me can we use c# or c++ in blender

Tags: c#, c++, graphics-programming, blender-game-engine

> > game development in blender with c#

---

## *hello everyone about me c# coding for games in blender game engine*

**how i can use blender in Android because i'm new student in game developement**
*Also about me how i use c# or c++ in game developement*

> > Can we use c++ for games making and development!

**How i use c++ for game development
Give me some programming language's example for learn and more knowledge about game development**

`can we use c++ in blender game engine`

Comment: If anyone don't understand so direct question me what he not understand  here because i want to know can we use c++ in blender game engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Using Blender as a 3D Modelling + Animation Tool & Integrating into an Android Project**

   This is definitely possible. Most game engines that run on Android devices will allow importing assets like models, animations, shaders and so on through various standard formats. Learn about [common 3D asset formats](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/data_system/files/import_export.html) and go from there.
2. **Using C++ as a Programming Language in Android Projects**

   [This is also possible](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/data_system/files/import_export.html) but may be needlessly complex if your goal isn't to learn C++ specifically. You may be better suited using Kotlin, Java, or even C# (assuming you're using something like Unity as your core game engine).

Comment: Thanks for help

Comment: You bet, good luck!